# Calling .stats() on grouped RDD (Spark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have an RDD which I am currently grouping and calculating basic descriptive statistics (count, sum, std, mean, etc.) using combineByKey.  It works fine, but seems like the RDD.stats() function will do what I need.

Right now, I am doing the following:

```
text_file = sc.textFile(input_source_file)
text_file.flatMap(zonal.zonal_stats)\
        .combineByKey(first_combiner, new_merge, final_combine)\
        .map(lambda (label, (value_sum, count, mx, mn)): "{},{},{},{},{},{},{}".format(label, value_sum, count, value_sum / count, mx, mn, mx - mn))\
        .saveAsTextFile(output_path)
```

How can I **replace combineByKey with the out-of-the-box .stats() function** and get basic statistics back for each group?

Comment: Could you share more code? What is your first_combiner, new_merge, final_combine?

Answer (score 0):

The stats function on Double RDDs isn't defined on a per-group basis. I'd suggest looking at using Spark SQL's `DataFrames` instead as they have summary stats aggregation functions defined on grouped data.

Another option would be to do your own reduction logic similar to how `stats()` is defined using the `StatsCounter` class.